# Submit form, don't save Into database, and display on page - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have one form on index page, when submit to some page (ex : `localhost:3000/:domainame`), 
I want it don't save into database and display some data.

```
def index
end

def who
  w = Whois::Client.new(:timeout => 20)
  @domainlook = w.lookup(params[:domainname])
end
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Why doesn't it work now? What is your current, unwanted behavior?

Comment: Add a route in your `routes.rb` to a controller that loads the data, and renders a view which displays this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple example implementation leveraging your sample code:

Create a POST match route:

```
# config/routes.rb
match 'who' => 'home#who', :via => :post
```

Set up a controller action for the route:

```
# app/controllers/home_controller.rb
def index
end

def who
    w = Whois::Client.new(:timeout => 20)
    @domainlook = w.lookup(params[:domainname])
end
```

The `index.html.erb` view should contain a form using the `form_tag` helper:

```
# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag who_path do %>

    <%= label_tag :domainname %>
    <%= text_field_tag :domainname %>

<% end %>
```

Finally, the `who.html.erb` view will render out your non-model instance variable:

```
# app/views/who.html.erb
<%= @domainlook %>
```